# What is Google Bot's default HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE?

Tags: seo, google-index

The default language of my site gets loaded depending on this value:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

If Google US indexes my site, will it use the 'us' lang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If Google US indexes my site, will it use the 'us' lang?

Yes, it is. To be more specific it's "en-us".